# django serializer validate field method wrong interpretation

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I should be wrong in my conclusion but I can't understand this in another way.
with this model:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field = serializers.CharField()
```

Normally django checks the field by it's own before working with the model, so you can't use c_field as interger because it's a char field.

Now, I want to add custom validation:

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
field = serializers.CharField()

```
def validate_field(self, data):
    if data == 'correct':
          return 'good'
    else:
          raise serializers.ValidationError('wrong data')
```

for me, it should be the correct way to use it, it add another 'validation' to that field, but I see it's been using in this way:

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
field = serializers.CharField()

```
def validate_field(self, data):
    if data == 'correct':
          return {'data': data}
```

and I don't understand it, because, it's returns something different, if you check it with:

```
res = serializer.ExampleSerializer(data={'field': 'field_char'})
res.is_valid()
res.data
```

and now data is a dict...
And here is what I don't understand, you can change it, so anyone that see the serializer get confused (and if you have a lot of validators you need to look for the correct one to understand what's happening), and the name it's confused to, because it's 'validate', not 'read_modify' or whatever.

So, I think it's another explanation that I can't find and understand. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation

Your use case of the first should be the preferred way. Using custom field-level validation by implementing a method in serializer with `validate_<field_name>` name, should return the same data type as the actual field. More details can be found [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation).

The reason why this code

```py
res = serializer.ExampleSerializer(data={'field': 'field_char'})
res.is_valid()
res.data
```

returns something different from what you expect it to be is because you access a wrong attribute.

- `.data` is the value of what will be serialized into JSON.
- `.validated_data` is the value of what will be deserialized into python object. Meaning that value that is returned from field-level validation via `validate_<field_name>` method in serializer will be the value of a field in `.validated_data`.

## Notes

If you want to perform multiple validations on a single field without mutating the value, you should use [`validators`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/)